# ServerVersion = 'conn.ServerVersion' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

Tags: c#, sql, .net

I've seen this error answered for other people, but I can't seem to get it to work.  I'm trying to connect to a SQL Server Database project locally.

I'm getting this error thrown on Open() when I do the follow:

```
SqlConnection conn = null;
conn = new SqlConnection(connection)
conn.Open()
```

Where connection is a connection string passed from my webconfig.  I've found examples online and tried these three connection strings and I get the same error every time:

```
<add name="TICKETING_CONNECTION" connectionString="Server=(local); DataBase=Ticketing_DB; Integrated Security=SSPI"/>

<add name="CONN"
connectionString="Data Source=localhost; Integrated Security=SSPI;Initial Catalog=Ticketing_DB"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

<add name="CONN2"
connectionString="Data Source=(local);Initial Catalog=Ticketing_DB;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"
/>
```

Could the problem be stemming from the path of where the database is located on my machine?  I've tried copying the c:\ path but didn't have any luck.  I've seen some examples online use a .mdf file, but my project does not have this file either.

This is my first time trying to connect to a database project, so any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Are you, by chance, using a named instance of SQL Server on your machine?  Perhaps SQL Server Express, which installs a named instance by default?  If so, your data source would be something like `localhost\sqlexpress`

Answer (score 8):

If you are using Visual Studio try going to the Server Explorer and Right click on Data Connections and Add new connection by selecting DataSource as Microsoft SQL Server and provider as .net framework provider for SQL Server.
Under the server name check for the SQL Server if it is listed with your machine name.
Then try to provide the database details and user name and password for SQL Authentication or select windows for windows authentication. Then do a test connection. If it is fine on click of OK it will add the data connection. 
Right click the properties of data connection which is newly added and navigate to properties to extract the connection string. Compare it with yours. This can help you troubleshoot the issue.

Comment: Thank you, my reason is "The password of the account has expired."
I uncheck "Enforce password expiration" on Login Properties. It works.

Comment: For me it didn't like the parentheses around systemname in the connectionstring although that worked fine except when using `using()`